# Populate main table with random employees (shuffled) from employee table based on department

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a task which I have been working on but am struggling finding the end result.

Task Description
Check each row in Main table

- If column a = ‘x’ then assign one of the 4 ‘x’ employees from employee table picked randomly to that row
- If column a = ‘y’ then get one of the 4 ‘y’ Standards officers from
  employee table picked randomly to that row

Employee Table

```
Id  Dept Employee
1   x   x1
2   x   x2
3   x   x3
4   x   x4
5   y   y1
6   y   y2
7   y   y3
8   y   y4
```

Main table (DATA) contains many columns and I need end column (Employee) to be populated by a Employee based on Dept and shuffled in employee table to randomize also.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please give a formatted table of what you wish. so we can visualize the desired structure.

Comment: @NavTuf - please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) showing the precise problem.

Comment: select top 10 so.name
from sys.sysobjects so
order by NEWID()

Comment: It seem good question,only thing is to throw sample data from both table to make your point clear and also show the output desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) [`Invoke-DbaDbDataMasking`](https://dbatools.io/masking/) and have the [New-DbaDbMaskingConfig](https://docs.dbatools.io/#New-DbaDbMaskingConfig) adjusted as per your requirements.

Above has some [limitations](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Invoke-DbaDbDataMasking) but it will help achieve what you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how many employees you have in each department and it's always the same (yes, big assumption), you can try to play with `row_number()` (to sort each employees in each departement and `newid()` to generate a [random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878287/generate-random-int-value-from-3-to-6).

For instance:

```
create table Emp (id int identity(1,1), dept char(1), Employee char(2))

insert into Emp
values( 'x', 'x1'),
    ( 'x', 'x2'),
    ( 'x', 'x3'),
    ( 'x', 'x4'),
    ( 'y', 'y1'),
    ( 'y', 'y2'),
    ( 'y', 'y3'),
    ( 'y', 'y4')

create table Dept (id int identity(1,1), dept char(1))

insert into Dept
values('x'), ('y'), ('x')

select a.id, a.dept, b.Employee
from (
    select *, abs(checksum(newid()) % 4) + 1 as r
    from Dept a
    ) a
left join (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by dept order by id) as r
    from Emp b
    ) b on a.dept = b.dept
        and a.r = b.r
```